# Cant Find Cinemachine Download

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm currently learning unity and I'm trying to download Cinemachine package but I cant find it in the package manager[Package Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JmZAU.png) or in the unity assets store[Assets Store](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oro3o.png),
Does someone have a link to it/ knows how to solve my problem,
thx!

Comment: In the picture "Package Manager" I've attached it doesn't display "My Assets", "In Project", "Unity Registry".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you open Package Manager, there are some kinds of assets to choose, there are "My Assets", "In Project", "Unity Registry". Most probably Cinemachine is in "Unity Registry".

[image]

Comment: Look in my screen shot, It doesn't show up. I don't understand where I need to click
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JmZAU.png

Comment: Probably is in "Packages: In Project". Try to change that for "Unity Registry".

Comment: Hey, Do you know any way to get Cinemachine for older Unity versions? I am using Unity 2017.2.5 (because it's the last version that supports DirectX 9). There is no package manager in that version.